# Scripting a way to quickly import OVPN files to NetworkManager on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn, vpn

I want to quickly import ovpn files into NetworkManager and append my login details into the final conf file that NetworkManager will use.

Basically turning this

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote italy.privateinternetaccess.com 1197
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.rsa.4096.pem
ca ca.rsa.4096.crt
disable-occ
```

into this

```
[connection]
id=Singapore
uuid=<unique id gen by uuidgen>
type=vpn
permissions=
secondaries=

[vpn]
connection-type=password
auth=SHA256
password-flags=0
remote=sg.privateinternetaccess.com:1197
cipher=AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo=yes
reneg-seconds=0
username=<username>
remote-cert-tls=server
ca=ca.rsa.4096.crt
dev=tun
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn

[vpn-secrets]
password=<password>

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Normally when NetworkManager imports the provided OVPN file, it outputs this.

```
[connection]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
id=Ireland
uuid=174fa5b0-0b49-40bc-a301-756acd341c12
type=vpn
permissions=
secondaries=

[vpn]
connection-type=password
auth=SHA256
password-flags=1
remote=ireland.privateinternetaccess.com:1197
cipher=AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo=yes
reneg-seconds=0
remote-cert-tls=server
ca=ca.rsa.4096.crt
dev=tun
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

I can quickly change passwords-flags via sed, but I'm at a lost on how to append the `username` and `[vpn-secrets]` section.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The new PIA OpenVPN config files contain some errors in them that may prevent an OpenVPN connection from starting.**

These are the errors.

```
...
cipher aes-256-cbc
auth sha-256
...
```

The fix is relative simple, just change them into fully uppercase. You can use sed to do it quickly for all the config files.

```
sed -i 's/aes-256-cbc/AES-256-CBC/g' *.ovpn

sed -i 's/sha256/SHA256/g' *.ovpn
```

**To quickly import the files using NetworkManager, use this command.**

```
for i in *.ovpn; do nmcli connection import file "$i" type openvpn; done
```

**If you wish to add in your username and password into the NetworkManager config file, follow these steps.**

First create a script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Changes password-flags from 1 to 0
sed -i 's/password-flags=1/password-flags=0/g' $1

# Adds in a username entry after reneg-seconds
sed -i '/reneg-seconds=0/a username=<insert username here>' $1

# Adds in a section [vpn-secrets] for passwords after line 21
sed -i '21 a [vpn-secrets]' $1

# Adds in password into the config file after [vpn-secrets]
sed -i '/\[vpn-secrets]/a password=<insert password here>' $1

# Adds in a new line after password=    
sed -i '/password=/a\\' $1
```

Navigate to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` or wherever NetworkManager stores its config files.

To quickly iterate the script over all the config files, run this command.

```
for i in "*"; do <script location> "$i"; done
```

Comment: Fabulous solution!

Comment: Doesn't work for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054634/how-to-do-a-mass-import-of-ovpn-files

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Have you tried looking into ProtonVPN's [script](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-tool/)?

Comment: @ghostinzshell which script? I've only found a cli tool

Comment: I found a solution and added as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of the script of ghostinzshell that works for ProtonVPN configs. Turns out he used the fixed line 21 to add vpn-secrets, I just added below some know text (service-type):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Changes password-flags from 1 to 0
sed -i 's/password-flags=1/password-flags=0/g' $1

# Adds in a username entry after reneg-seconds
sed -i '/reneg-seconds=0/a username=USERNAME_HERE' $1

# Adds in password into the config file after [vpn-secrets]
sed -i '/service-type=/a\
\
[vpn-secrets]' $1
sed -i '/\[vpn-secrets]/a password=PASSWORD_HERE' $1
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a script which does this using only the officially supported API (no `sed` munging):

```bsh
#! /bin/sh

read -sp 'Username: ' username
echo
read -sp 'Password: ' password

for path in "$@"
do
    name=$(basename "$path" ".ovpn")

    sudo nmcli --terse connection delete id "$name" > /dev/null
    sudo nmcli --terse connection import type openvpn file "$path" > /dev/null

    sudo nmcli connection modify "$name" vpn.persistent true
    sudo nmcli connection modify "$name" vpn.user-name "$username"
    sudo nmcli connection modify "$name" +vpn.data "password-flags = 0, username = $username"
    sudo nmcli connection modify "$name" +vpn.secrets "password=$password"
done

echo
```

Assuming that the script is called `import-openvpn`, you can use it like this:

```bsh
$ import-openvpn *.ovpn
Username:
Password:
```

This will delete the existing VPN connections, and then remake them with the specified username and password.